# .NET API for Google Talk?

Tags: .net, api, open-source, google-talk

I am looking for a .NET API for Google-Talk (talk/voice/video/file).

Any resources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Google Talk API for C#.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089816/need-google-talk-api-for-c-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Talk uses [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/). [Here's a .NET API](http://www.ag-software.de/index.php?page=agsxmpp-sdk) for this protocol. And there's a [list of other libraries](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#csharp).

Comment: It's only for text chat, do you have any resources for voice/video/ft .NET engine?