# Need google chat API in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, google-api

am new to C#. I am looking for API which provides google chat features.
Can anyone share the API url and sample code would be more helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET API for Google Talk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214914/net-api-for-google-talk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Google Talk API for C#.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089816/need-google-talk-api-for-c-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use any XMPP library.  There are a bunch out there for .net, one I've dabbled in can be found here: http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/

Google found this article that may give some good examples.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=346

And from http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html#developer

> You need to know the following: The
>   service is hosted at talk.google.com
>   on port 5222 TLS is required The only
>   supported authentication mechanism is
>   SASL PLAIN