# Need Google Talk API for C#.Net

Tags: c#

Any one know Google Talk Api for C#.Net?, Please help.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Google Talk for Developers](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/talk/).

It uses the Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) (Originally called Jabber as @kbok mentioned).

There are numerous XMPP libraries available for .NET. The agsXMPP SDK .NET library being one of them.

Here's a tutorial in C# to get you started:

[Google Talk (GTalk) Autoreply using .NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=346)

Comment: How i used my Google Application domain, other then using gmail.com.

Comment: Its work when I try using example@gmail.com but how I can login using test@test.com where @test.com is my domain for google apps.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chat uses the Jabber(AKA XMPP) protocol behind the hood. You can find a .NET binding here : http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

Answer (score 1):

[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/googletalk.aspx) uses [Jabber.net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) to access Google Chat. That should get you started.