# How to open gchat connection in the windows 8 metro App StreamSocket instead of localhost?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I've seen an **StreamSocket** Example from msdn

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931

In the above example they have connected with **localhost** and send message, can we able to connect to **talk.google.com** and enable **chat**.

If anybody knows means please say me!

Comment: You don't need to go low-level TCP for accessing google talk. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089816/need-google-talk-api-for-c-net

Comment: agsXMPP,Jabber-Net are not working in Metro App. Matrix will work but its not for free. .  Thats y asked sir. . .